# What is the highest power of 3 that divides a string of 3^2013 digit 3s?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

I have come up with a solution to the following question:
A number written in base 10 is a string of 3^2013 digit 3s. No other
digit appears. Find the highest power of 3 which divides this number.

However after looking up the answer it appears I have made a mistake somewhere that I cannot spot.

Here is my solution,

Let the number = $3+3*10 + 3*10^2+...+3*10^{2012}$. The 3 can then be factored out to get a geometric sum which then sums to $\frac{10^{2013}-1}{3}$.

The numerator can be expanded to give $(10-1)(10^{2012}-10^{2011}-...-10+1)$ hence the number simplifies to $3(10^{2012}-10^{2011}-...-10+1)$

Ignoring the 3 on the front for now and considering the expression (mod 3) it gives, $10^{2012}-10^{1011}-...-10+1 \cong 1 - 1 - 1-...-1+1 = 2 - 2011 = -2009$

2009 is not divisible by 3 and so this does not reduce to 0 (mod 3) hence the highest power of 3 that divides the expression is 3.

This is clearly incorrect as its easy to show the number is at least divisible by 9 using divisibility rules, however I'm not sure why. Thanks for any help.

Comment: $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+1)$

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very stupid of me!

Comment: I believe the number being described is not $\displaystyle \frac{10^{2013}-1}{3}$ but rather $\displaystyle \frac{10^{3^{2013}}-1}{3}$.

Comment: Your number has only 2013 digits, not 3^2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for being incorrect is already in comments, if you use the right expression $\dfrac{10^{3^{2013}}-1}3$ for your number you'll find it is divisible by $9$.  In fact it is divisible by a higher power of $3$.

---

Let the number made of a string of $3^k$ threes be $S_k$.  Then we can show the stronger claim that $S_k \equiv 3^{k+1} \mod {3^{k+2}}$, which is enough to conclude that the power you seek is $3^{2014}$.

The base case for an induction argument is easy with $k=0$ or $k=1$. For the induction step, note $S_{k+1} = S_k \cdot \left(10^{3^{k+1}}+10^{3^k}+1 \right)$

By the induction hypothesis, we have $S_k = a\cdot 3^{k+2}+3^{k+1}$, for some $a \in \mathbb N$.  Further, obviously $10^{3^{k+1}}+10^{3^k}+1 \equiv 3 \pmod 9 $, hence $10^{3^{k+1}}+10^{3^k}+1 = 9b+3$ for some $b\in \mathbb N$.

Therefore we have the induction step
$$S_{k+1} = S_k \cdot \left(10^{3^{k+1}}+10^{3^k}+1 \right) = \left(a\cdot 3^{k+2}+3^{k+1}\right)\cdot(9b+3) \equiv 3^{k+2} \pmod {3^{k+3}}$$